# Missing Columns from Datatable once Grouped C# ODBC Datatable Console App

Tags: c#

I have a datatable named completeDT_units. I group the column "Account#" and sum "Cur-Balance...."

The grp is copied to a new data table.

How do I modify the below code to also copy over "Description" that is not copied over in the below code?

Thanks

```
//GROUP FOR COUNTS
var accountGroups = completeDT_units.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(row => row.Field<String>("Account#"))
                .Select(grp => new { Account = grp.Key, Count = grp.Sum(row => row.Field<int>("Cur-Balance....")) });

var tblAccCounts = new DataTable();
tblAccCounts.Columns.Add("Account#");
tblAccCounts.Columns.Add("Cur-Balance....");

foreach (var grp in accountGroups)
    tblAccCounts.Rows.Add(grp.Account, grp.Count);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use new keyword and add description to grouping

```
var accountGroups = completeDT_units.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => new { row => row.Field<String>("Account#"), 
                        Description = row.Field<string>("Description").ToString() })
    .Select(grp => new { Account = grp.Key.row,
                         descrpt = grp.Key.Description, 
                         Count = grp.Sum(row => row.Field<int>("Cur-Balance....")) });
```